# How can I remove the notes from several (but not all) slides at once in Microsoft PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, slideshow

I wonder how I can remove the notes from several (but not all) slides at once in Microsoft PowerPoint.

---

I [know](https://www.howtogeek.com/730732/how-to-delete-all-presentation-notes-at-once-in-microsoft-powerpoint/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20presentation%20notes%20using,and%20hitting%20your%20Delete%20key.) how to remove the notes from all the slides as shown below, but I just want to remove in several slides:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go to each slide one by one in either Notes Pages view or Slide View with the Notes pane showing. If you want to delete the notes from the slide, click within the notes, press Ctrl+A to select all the text, press DEL.  By the way, it's a lot of unnecessary (and possibly confusing) work to describe what you DON'T want to do in such detail.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg got it, thanks!

Comment: Just thought I'd add:  If there's some way of identifying the notes text that's to be remove (or the slide it's attached to), this could be automated. For example, if the notes to be removed included some key word that's not present in the notes text that should stay.